# How do you decide what to test in your test suites?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, functional-testing

I'm an intern working on a project that has the potential to introduce a lot of bugs at a company with an extremely large code base. Currently the company has no automated testing implemented for any of their projects, so I want to begin writing tests for the code as I go so that I can tell when I break something, but I have a hard time developing an intuition for what is worth testing and how to test it. Some things are more obvious than others: testing string manipulation functions isn't too tough, but what to write for a multithreaded custom memory manager is trickier.

How do *you* go about designing tests for an existing codebase and what do you test for? How do you figure out what underlying assumptions the code is making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to most of your questions 
[http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

Comment: Just received the book from Amazon. It's a great resource!

Comment: glad my suggestion was useful

Answer (score 1):

No easy answers for you I'm afraid. That is just a tough spot to be in.

The method to be applied is

- identify regions that deliver the most bang-for-test-buck. (This is something that you have to come up with - unique to your situation).
- Spend time getting to know the region. Identify interactions of this region with the rest of the code base.
- Document the same using tests - these act as a regression "vice" that will hold your software in place while you make subsequent changes
- Now you've a safety net to work above. You can now start making your enhancements/fixes/changes using a TDD approach.

The idea is slowly islands of the codebase will emerge above the safety net till you reach a point of diminishing returns. Michael feather's WELC book as posted by Pangea above is a must-read if you're venturing into this area.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348089/getting-started-with-automated-integration-unit-testing-in-an-existing-code-base)

Some quick thoughts from me:

- At the beginning, add tests for new
  written code, either in new project
  or for changes on a existing project.
- Don't touch code that is running and is not changed.
- concentrate on functionality that is
  often used or that is critical.

The subject is really manifold and maybe you should try to get a training to get an overview. Assuming you are in the US, you can have a closer look [here](http://www.astqb.org/). Here is their [course content](http://www.astqb.org/educational-resources/syllabi.php).

They have also a long [list of useful resources](http://www.astqb.org/educational-resources/publications.php#books).